# COUNTIF in SharePoint to get total based on a text character

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list that is built from values submitted from an InfoPath form..

I've got a view that just displays the columns I'm interested in...

[image: sample of data]

I'm trying to get the output below - countif where the cell contains 'Y'

I need to get an output in another results view similar to this:

```
Event | Total
-------------
28PM  | 0
29AM  | 0
29PM  | 3
30AM  | 1
31AM  | 2
31PM  | 4
1AM   | 2
1PM   | 6
```

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that across multiple list items natively in SharePoint.

You can add the "TOTAL" feature to the view when filtering for "Y", or you'll have to Export to Excel and make the formulas in there.

Comment: it's not from multiple lists - all the data in the screenshot is from one list. It's just each row is an individual submission and I need to count the number of times that 'Y' features in each row and sum those by column.. I'm trying to built a graph of the results using a third party app that needs the output in the format of the table I included.

Comment: right, but this is multiple rows, or in SharePoint terms -- "multiple list items"

Comment: Mike - That's correct I've decided to come at it from a different angle and using 1/0 instead of Y/N to capture the data so I can do the calculations. Thanks